# CSS - Select all elements that are outside of a particular element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to select all elements which are outside of my container div using CSS and would like to know how this is done.

I attempted to select all elements which are not container elements - `:not(container)` - but this results in all elements which are **contained** in the `container` element to be affected too.

I am looking to do something along the lines of the following:

> Apply this to all elements OUTSIDE of 'container'
>   do NOT include elements contained WITHIN 'container'.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a short example to show the problem?

Comment: i think this is not possible with css only, but you can set desired style to ALL elements on page and then unset it on those in 'container' like "div {font-weight: bold;} .container div {font-weight: normal;}"

Comment: If you show us your HTML we might be able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
(parent element) > *:not(container)
```

">" selects all direct children of the parent element specified, unfortunatly this will not work if you have divs outside the container that are not direct descendants of the parent but you could use multiple selectors such as:

```
(parent element) > *:not(container) > *:not(container)
```

You will need to replace `(parent element)` with your chosen selector

Comment: OP's way of writing `:not(container)` is correct. No quotes, and no need for `*`.

Comment: oh yes - sorry i must have been thinking of contains. corrected.

Comment: Thank you, Jamie - this is great.  I just put `html > :not(container)` and that solved my problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Mick: You mean `body > :not(container)`? Because `html`'s children, `head` and `body`, are `:not(container)` :P

Comment: Sadly this is [not supported by MS IE](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-not).

Comment: @BoltClock Actually, no, I don't mean that :-P - I understand your point entirely, (and to be honest, I tried using `body > :not(container)` first of all, which didn't work) but it did work with `html > :not(container)`!

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick for me:

```
parent:not(container) {}
```